# how to Circos plot for E.coli genome with several tracks around the circle showing different strains on R

Tags: r, variant, circlize, circos

I need to create a Circos plot to compare mutations between different strains. I would prefer to use an R package for this purpose. The desired output should resemble the example shown in this link http://book.bionumbers.org/what-is-the-mutation-rate-during-genome-replication/

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_examples/

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to give you a worked example if you don't share (a link to) the data.